# Couldn't call JpaRepository in test unit

Tags: java, jpa, testing, methods, entity

I want to test a serviceImpl (UpdateServiceImpl), the test is like:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class UpdateUserServiceImplTests {

    @Spy
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Mock
    private UserInfoUpdate userInfoUpdate;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository1;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private UpdateUserServiceImpl updateUserServiceImpl;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setupMock() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        userInfoUpdate = new UserInfoUpdate();
    }

    @Test
    public void makeUserInfoRight (){

            try {
                System.out.println(userInfoUpdate.getUsername());
                User user = updateUserServiceImpl.makeUserInfoFull(userInfoUpdate);
                User user_to_update = userRepository1.findById(userInfoUpdate.getUsername())
                        .orElseThrow(() 
                        -> new UserNotFoundException("User not found by thisusername : " + "{" +
                         userInfoUpdate.getUsername() + "}"));
}
```

And the Method ( makeUserInfoFull() ) in updateUserServiceImpl to be tested is like:

```
@Service
public class UpdateUserServiceImpl implements UpdateUserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    InfoGuess infoGuess;

    @Override
    public User makeUserInfoFull(UserInfoUpdate userInfoUpdate)
            throws UserNotFoundException {

        User user_to_update =
                userRepository.findById(userInfoUpdate.getUsername())
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("User not found by this username : " + "{" + userInfoUpdate.getUsername() + "}"));
```

The repository is simple one:

```
@Service
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
}
```

The JpaRepository interface works fine through @Autowired in test unit (generated userRepository1), but the interface in Method ( makeUserInfoFull() ) I tried @Spy to mock into the test, the Repository (for example:  userRepository.findAll() ) keeps return null result.
Is that no way to use real data in the test through JpaRepositoy?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock that repository also as follow.

```
@Mock
UserRepository userRepository1;
```

Then it will be injected within that service class.

Then you can use mockito when call and return what you want.
Mockito.when(userRepository1.findById(anyString()).thenReturn(object)

Comment: The userRepository1 used in test (through @Autowired) works fine.
The Impl (UpdateUserServiceImpl) I want to test alos use interface repository (userRepository), which I use @Spy to , expected it can run in  UpdateUserServiceImpl but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not good to use real data on unit test, because:

1. The database will dirty of test data (contains positive and negative case)
2. It doesn't make any sense if whenever we have to update our code to avoid that the data is empty or already exist.
3. Relate with no.2, the unit test should be independent. Not depend on other test even database.

In my opinion, we have two options:

1. Use Mockito to mock another service such as database or even 3rd party integration. To make our unit test more independent and also faster than using @SpringBootTest
2. If we are really have to use database integration, you can use H2 Database for your unit test only. So in the real environment you are using Mysql or anything, and using H2 Database only for Unit Test

[image]